# When installing pbc for Mylar, error: cannot find install-sh, > install.sh, or shtool

Tags: linux

I am trying to install Mylar.

http://css.csail.mit.edu/mylar/

The instructions advise that it requires several prerequisites:

- libreadline
- libgmp
- libpbc
- libcrypto++9

I believe I installed the first two correctly with apt-get.

also libgmp-dev and libreadline-dev both show up with "i" in aptitude, so I guess that means that they installed properly.

I am pretty sure that libpbc is not installed correctly.

It is available from:

http://repo.or.cz/w/pbc.git

I tried to use git to get it, and git made a directory for it, but when I try to do ./configure in that directory, I get:

> ./configure ./configure: line 2175: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE: command not found ./configure: line 2180: LT_INIT: command not found ./configure:
>   line 2212: AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_DLL: command not found checking for gcc...
>   gcc checking whether the C compiler works... yes checking for C
>   compiler default output file name... a.out checking for suffix of
>   executables...  checking whether we are cross compiling... no checking
>   for suffix of object files... o checking whether we are using the GNU
>   C compiler... yes checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes checking for
>   gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed ./configure: line 3038:
>   AM_PROG_CC_C_O: command not found checking how to run the C
>   preprocessor... gcc -E configure: error: cannot find install-sh,
>   install.sh, or shtool in "." "./.." "./../.."

and that is clearly lacking at least one requirement.

Comment: Try with `autoreconfig --install` first